# Removing user input from a Text file

Tags: python, text-files

I am trying to remove specific student ID numbers from a text file. the first if can verify if an ID is in the file. the second can add to the file but the third I just can't get any solutions to work for me.

```
def change_memberships():
    membership = ''
    verify = ''
    filename = 'Member.txt.txt'
    new_a_num = ''
    remove_mem = ''
    id_ = ''
    
    print('1) Verify an existing account?')
    print('2) Add a new member?')
    print('3) Remove a member?')
    membership = input('Which would you like to do: ')

    if membership == '1':
        verify = input('Please enter a Middlesex ID number: ')
                
                
        #Open file and check if the A number is in the file or not
        with open(filename) as f_obj:
            Anumber = f_obj.read()

            name_to_check = verify
            #If A number is in file return discount
            if name_to_check in Anumber:
                print('This ID has a preexisting account.')
                #If A number is not in file return 'A number not in file'
            else:
                print('This Student ID number is not in our records.')
    elif membership == '2':
        file = open('Member.txt.txt', "a")
        new_a_num = input('Please enter the MCC Student ID number you wish to add: ')
        file.write('\n' + new_a_num)
        print('MCC Student ID has been added.')
        file.close()
    elif membership == '3':
        remove_mem = input('Please enter the MCC Student ID number you wish to remove: ')




change_memberships()
```

I have tried importing my files and variables in about 6 or 7 different solutions to the exact same problem I am having from this website but they all either deleted all the IDs in my file, did nothing at all or just added random spaces around the ID I'm trying to remove, indentations and large spaces between the IDs in the file. I have no idea where to even begin now because each solution I have tried has different code, so I don't know what's right or wrong anymore.

Comment: Generally it's easier to read the existing file item-by-item, copy the items you want to keep to a new file, and then rename the new file to the existing name, instead of actually removing items from the existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first read the files and get the `list of current Ids`, then open the file with `'w'` (create a new blank file), and check if each `Id` in `list of current Ids` equal to `removed Id`. If it doesn't then write that `Id` in `list of current Ids` to the new blank file, else (`Id` = `removed Id`) then skip that `Id` (doesn't write to new file).

```
def change_memberships():
    membership = ''
    verify = ''
    filename = 'sof.txt'
    new_a_num = ''
    remove_mem = ''
    id_ = ''
    print('1) Verify an existing account?')
    print('2) Add a new member?')
    print('3) Remove a member?')
    membership = input('Which would you like to do: ')

    if membership == '1':
        verify = input('Please enter a Middlesex ID number: ')

        # Open file and check if the ID is in the file or not
        with open(filename) as f_obj:
            Anumber = f_obj.read()

            name_to_check = verify
            # If ID is in file return discount
            if name_to_check in Anumber:
                print('This ID has a preexisting account.')
            # If ID is not in file return 'ID not in file'
            else:
                print('This Student ID number is not in our records.')
    elif membership == '2':
        file = open('sof.txt', "a")
        new_a_num = input('Please enter the MCC Student ID number you wish to add: ')
        file.write('\n' + new_a_num)
        print('MCC Student ID has been added.')
        file.close()
    elif membership == '3':
        remove_mem = input('Please enter the MCC Student ID number you wish to remove: ')
        # Open the file and read the contents into a list
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        # Iterate through the list, write Id to new file if it isn't equal removed_mem
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            removed = False
            for line in lines:
                if line.strip() == remove_mem:
                    removed = True
                    print('ID number removed.')
                else:
                    f.write(line)
            if not removed:
                print('ID number not found in file.')


change_memberships()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_mem = input('Please enter the MCC Student ID number you wish to remove:')
data = open('text.txt').read()
data = data.replace(remove_mem, '')
```

In this code we replace all occurrences of remove_mem with nothing.

Comment: Thank you for responding I copied this code and inserted my file name. when I run it and type the ID i wish to remove, I then open the file and the id is still in there unfortunately.

Comment: This solution is missing the important steps of then closing the file, reopening the file in write mode, and then writing the new file with the replacement data.  I'd have to test, but it may also result in leaving a blank line in the file because it is only replacing the ID number to remove, and not the surrounding whitespace.